# Custom Tokens for large dataset?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

In Firestore I have a large set of documents (with sub-collections under it), and I have 3 roles ("Admin", "Semi-Admin", and "Users"). By default every new user has no access at all, and then they might gain "User" access to 3 documents, and "Admin" to 2 and "Semi" to say 1.

I wanted to do this with custom tokens, but that means that I'll need to create 3 fields for every document, which will quickly bust through the 1000 bytes limit.

My question is if I can still do it this way and just add the documents to the token which they do have access on (meaning that if they don't have that key:value pair the default is no access), or is that not a great way to do it?

The alternative is just having a Cloud Function or Security Rule looking up a value in their user profile, but that will lead to a lot of reads.

The ideal would be a "custom token" sort of thing, but that is document specific and not user specific... any thoughts?

Comment: It will be easier to help if you show examples of the data you're working with.  Right now it's kind of difficult to imagine what you're trying to do and what the problem is with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you're looking to build a document-level access control list with different permissions levels for individual users. Trying to store the list of documents the user has access to in the ID token of the user is indeed quickly going to lead to a token than is bigger than allowed (and would also increase the bandwidth charges that your users incur).

The solution is to store the necessary information in the database itself, and read it in your security rules. There is no way to prevent the extra document read charge this will incur, but it should be possible to limited it to one extra read per document read or query.

---

The only alternative I can think of is to keep a separate area in the database for each user with the document they access to split by the three roles you have. This would lead to a lot of data duplication though, which I doubt would outweigh the savings in document reads from the security rules.